# Twitter API - Difference between "Authorize App" and "Sign in"

Tags: twitter

Simple question - My web app uses the Twitter API - and the button it presents to users on oAuth "Sign In".

But I've seen other web apps (such as Quora) - where the prompt is connect with twitter and the button says "Authorize App".

Anyone know what the difference is? Authorize app is more accurate for my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are actually called authorize and authenticate.

The primary difference is simple: one will ask you to confirm the access every time you view the OAuth page, the other will automatically approve it for you if you have accepted it in the past.

There are a few limitations on the second (authenticate) flow, such as not being able to view DMs. This is because of privacy reasons.

Comment: Tom - thanks. Just to clarify - which gives me (the website admin) persistent oAuth tokens for the user? I don't want my users to have to approve it every time. Should I use "Sign In" (authenticate?) or "Authorize App" (authorize?)?

Comment: Both are persistent, but /authenticate will automatically authorize the user when he/she has done that in the past.